# Prevent accidental event bubbling up on element

Tags: css, dom, jquery

I am trying to create a simple hover effect on a list elements. But, there is small gap between the element that shows up when mouse is over the list item. This forces the event `mouseleave` to be triggered, which is unwanted.

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvyVZ/) demo. Try to go to the small box after hovering over the list item.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>test <div class="block">Block</div></li>
    <li>test2 <div class="block">Block descriptions</div></li>
</ul>​
```

CSS:

```
ul { width: 50px; }
ul li { width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #c00; margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
li .block { 
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0 0 0 70px;
    background: #ddd;
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("ul li").hover(function() {
    $(this).children(".block").stop().fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).children(".block").stop().fadeOut();
});​
```

How to prevent such effect?

Comment: The `mouseleave` event is triggered because you literally leave the element when you ty to move the mouse over to the child. The only solution is to extend the width of the `li` element.

Comment: @FelixKling, Yes, but as you see `li` is in icon shape and I can't do that. May be, there is a way to check where the mouse is? and if it is in the `.block` then dont bubble the event, otherwise do bubble it.

Comment: Can't you change the HTML? Something like this would work: http://jsfiddle.net/pvyVZ/5/. The problem is not with `.block`. If you move the mouse quickly enough you'll see that the block actually stays . The `mouseleave` event is still triggered but since the fade out is slow, `mouseenter` is triggered when you hover over `.block`. You cannot prevent the `mouseleave` from triggering if you don't extend the `li` size. This has nothing to do with event bubbling.

Comment: @FelixKling, Yes, I could. Let me try that on my actual problem.

Comment: @FelixKling, I implemented your solution like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pvyVZ/9/). Basically it works, thanks to you :). but when we are going from one icon to another icon rapidly, same animated loops again and again. How to prevent this?

Comment: @FelixKling, I solved the problem, with a `stop()`. Please change the comments into an answer. I read the manual, but I can't understand what `stop()` does? If you could please help me out on that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mouseleave` event is triggered because you literally leave the element when you ty to move the mouse over to the child. The only solution is to extend the width of the `li` element.

The maintain the same look, I suggest to move the red box into its own element, for example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="icon">test</span> 
        <span class="block">Block</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="icon">test2</span> 
        <span class="block">Block descriptions</span>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

And change the CSS to:

```
li span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

li .icon {
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    background: #c00;
}

li .block { 
    margin: 0 0 0 70px;
    background: #ddd;
    display: none;
}
```

The `li` element extends over both children: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvyVZ/10/). <del>Note though that `display: inline-block` might not work in older IE versions.</del> (should be fine according to http://caniuse.com/inline-block).

Comment: So, what can be the solution without the `inline-block`?

Comment: I have to correct myself, according to http://caniuse.com/inline-block, it should be fine. But I have no IE to test it. An alternative could be to use `div`'s and `float` but then you have to set a fixed size for `.block` and floats are a bit tricky to get right...

Comment: @FelixKling yeah inline-block works in IE for inline elements (like span), but wouldn't work properly on <div> as this is a block element by default.

Comment: I am trying this solution here http://jsfiddle.net/y4LMk/1/, but it is  not working while I browse over the box. Please see

Answer (score 1):

Try **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pvyVZ/22/)**:

```
$('ul li').on("mouseenter mouseleave",function( e ){
   var $this = $(this);
   if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
       clearTimeout( $this.data('timeout') );
       $this.find('.block').stop().fadeTo(400,1);
   }else{
       $this.data( 'timeout', setTimeout(function(){
           $this.find('.block').stop().fadeTo(200,0, function(){
             $(this).hide(); 
           });
       },200) );
   }
});
```

What it does is: set a timeout value to the `data` attribute of the currently hovered `li` element that will act like a *hover intent* that will wait 200ms for the mouseenter on your `.block` elements maintaining the element visible. Once the mouse reaches your block element it will reset the timeout.

Comment: What does this `stop()` function do?

Comment: It does not solve the problem though, it just fixes the animation.

Comment: @mrN the `.stop()` clears animation queue so you don't get repeated flashing `.block` elements

Comment: I fixed the flashing problem on Felix's solution with `.stop()`. Thank you (+1) :)

Comment: Can you also take a look at this, http://jsfiddle.net/y4LMk/1/? I am trying to do the same with a bit complicated markup, but the box is still flashing.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work. might need a couple of tweaks.

http://jsfiddle.net/G5YfR/

```
var fn = function(elem) {
    $(elem).children(".block").fadeOut();
};
var timeout;
$("ul li").on("mouseenter", function() {
    var that = this;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $(this).children(".block").fadeIn();
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    var that = this;

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        fn(that)
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements with mouse event handlers attached, and they are placed with a little distance from each other, so when the mouse is leaving one element on the way to the other element it goes outside both element and the event handler is triggered again etc.

You can either place both elements inside a wrapper element and attach the event handler to that element

```
<ul>
    <li><div>test <div class="block">Block</div></div></li>
    <li><div>test2 <div class="block">Block descriptions</div></div></li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

js:

```
$("ul li").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(".block", this).fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(".block", this).fadeOut();
    }
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvyVZ/6/)

or you can try to guesstimate the time it takes to move the mouse and use a little timeout to fake it:

```
var timer;

$("ul li").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).children(".block").fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        var self = this;
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $(self).children(".block").fadeOut();
        }, 400);
    }
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvyVZ/4/)